# How to generate dynamic chart images in Springboot using JavaFx

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx

## Problem

Displaying dynamic chart images based on query parameters

### Question

How do I use JavaFX to generate chart images in a Web Service(possibly a Springboot application) the right way?

### Application

I followed through http://www.greggbolinger.com/let-spring-be-your-javafx-controller-factory/ and created a custom Application which extends javafx.application.Application

### My Controller

```java
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String austria = "Austria";
    String brazil = "Brazil";
    String france = "France";
    String italy = "Italy";
    String usa = "USA";
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
            new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();
    //stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
    sbc.setTitle("Country Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Country");
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(
            Arrays.asList(austria, brazil, france, italy, usa)));
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");
    series1.setName("2003");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 25601.34));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 20148.82));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(france, 10000));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(italy, 35407.15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(usa, 12000));
    series2.setName("2004");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 57401.85));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 41941.19));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(france, 45263.37));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(italy, 117320.16));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(usa, 14845.27));
    series3.setName("2005");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 45000.65));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 44835.76));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(france, 18722.18));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(italy, 17557.31));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(usa, 92633.68));
    sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
    final WritableImage[] snapshot = new WritableImage[1];
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        /*
         * This line throws a exception with the following message
         * (if not inside Platform.runLater):
         * "Not on FX application thread"
         */
        snapshot[0] = scene.snapshot(null);
    });

    // This is bad code, how to work around it?
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot[0], null), "png", output);
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @PSM no and also read this: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/java/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html

Comment: @Ravuteja thanks.Now I am using JFree chart instead of javaFx